# Changing color of IBAction with FlatUIKit?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am trying to changing the visual aspects of my button, however I am trying to use the FlatUIKit's button aspect, for those who don't know what that is that ok as it doesn't matter, in the example project that they provide they change the color of an IBOutlet button however it dosen't work the same with an IBAction heres their example code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FUIButton.h"
#import "UIColor+FlatUI.h"

@interface ViewController () 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FUIButton *alertViewButton;

//as you can see its a FUIButton, and I'm not sure how to use that with an IBAction

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 self.alertViewButton.buttonColor = [UIColor peterRiverColor];
self.alertViewButton.shadowColor = [UIColor silverColor];
self.alertViewButton.shadowHeight = 3.0f;
self.alertViewButton.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
self.alertViewButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:16];
[self.alertViewButton setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.alertViewButton setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

}
```

Heres my code this far:

my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {


}
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;


@end
```

my .m:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "UIColor+FlatUI.h"
#import "FUIButton.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()



@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {

//this is the button i want change the appearance of.
}
```

I am stuck with this, the button I want to use the FUIButton color effects is the IBAction called start, any help? Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using storyboards if that makes a difference.

Comment: An `IBAction` is just a method that you can connect in Interface Builder, not a UI element.

Comment: How can u change the UIelement though, in the viewdidload?

Comment: Is `alertViewButton` the button you want to change the color of?

Comment: no, i want to change the color of IBAction "start", the alertviewButton is the example that was given with the framework

Comment: You can't change the color of an IBAction, that's just a method. It isn't shown on the screen. The example `alertViewButton` is what you can change the color of. If you want to change the color of that button, just put the code to do that in the method `start:`.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: If you want to set attributes of the button you need to declare the button as an IBOutlet in your .h and link the button to that in the XIB, just as you would for a label or an image or whatever.  This is separate from linking the button to the IBAction name for doing the button action.